# Grid image gallery - Width is responsive but need height to be responsive too

Tags: html, css, image, gallery, responsive-design

My grid image gallery has four images on each line. The width:25% in the CSS makes the width responsive but I need the height to also be responsive. At the moment I have the height as 180px. Could I set it as a percentage to make it responsive like the width? I've tried but when I set it as a percentage it doesn't work. It only works if I move height:x% to line1 img/line2 img, but then the image becomes squashed.

```
<div class="line1">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" />
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3.jpg" />
<img src="image4.jpg" alt="image4.jpg" /></div>

<div class="line2">
<img src="image5.jpg" alt="image5.jpg" />
<img src="image6.jpg" alt="image6.jpg" />
<img src="image7.jpg" alt="image7.jpg" />
<img src="image8.jpg" alt="image8.jpg" /></div>


.line1{
overflow:hidden;    
height:180px;
}
.line1 img{
width:25%;
}
.line2{
overflow:hidden;    
height:180px;
}
.line2 img{
width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both `.line1{ height: auto;}` and `.line1{ height: auto;` this will keep it responsive.
Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YeecL/) example.